# RVM / rbenv / terminal $PATH error: (eval):18: parse error near `PATH=/usr/local/opt/...'

Tags: macos, terminal, path, rvm, rbenv

I noticed the following error in my Mac (Monterey version 12.4) terminal upon opening it today:

`` (eval):18: parse error near `PATH=/usr/local/opt/...' ``

I suspected that it was related to my installation and removal of Ruby Version Manager (RVM - https://rvm.io/) last week. When I tried using RVM to install Ruby 2.6.1, the installation failed, and upon doing some research, it looked like RVM has issues with install older versions of Ruby on Macs. Therefore, I removed RVM and installed rbenv instead, which worked. Anyway, to uninstall RVM, I ran:

`rvm implode`

I also removed an RVM line from my bash_profile. This was all done last week.

Upon seeing this new error in my terminal, I ran `echo $PATH`, which output this:

`/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/francoortega/.rvm/bin`

I'm guessing that the .rvm part of this $PATH may be part of the problem.

Next I ran `open ~/.bash_profile` and `open ~/.bashrc`, which had this info:

**bash_profile**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

**bashrc**

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

I tried deleting the rvm info from these files, but that didn't have any effect, so I undid those deletions. Also, it seemed odd that the bash_profile had a line that include ***rvm*** and ***rbenv*** info

Then, I ran `open ~/.zshrc`, which output this:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.10/bin:$PATH"
```

I tried deleting the .rvm line, but that had no effect, so I undid that deletion. Then, surprisingly, when I deleted the rbenv file, this removed the terminal error.

1. However, I don't want to delete rbenv, so I'm not sure what would be the proper way to fix this error.
2. Additionally, I wasn't able to find the path listed in the error (`/usr/local/opt/`) either.
3. And since I no longer have RVM, should I delete the rvm lines from the bash_profile bashrc, and .zshrc files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following steps solved my issue:

1. Removed this line from .zshrc:

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.10/bin:$PATH"
```

2. Removed this line from .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

3. Removed these two lines from .bashrc and .zshrc:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

My .bashrc and .zshrc files are now empty, and my .bash_profile only contains:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
```

My terminal now open without any error message.

Also, I found it strange that the line in my .bash_profile mentioned both ***rvm*** and ***rbenv*** (see original post above), but reading the rbenv docs, it turns out that I was supposed to remove rvm before installing rbenv, so maybe having rvm on my machine when I install rbenv is what led to this mashup.

Finally, as I mentioned in my original post, I had already removed rvm, but today I removed rbenv with the following two commands (it had been installed via Homebrew):

```
rm -rf `rbenv root`
brew uninstall rbenv
```